# Javascript undefined error: `this` is null

Tags: javascript, undefined

Somehow when executing this code, I get the alert from **line 29** .mouseOnSeat.
But I don't know why *this.seats* is null, while in the **draw** function it is not.
I call the init function from html5.

```
//init called by html5
function init() {
  var cinema = new Cinema(8, 10);
  cinema.draw("simpleCanvas");

  var canvas = document.getElementById("simpleCanvas");
  //add event listener and call mouseOnSeat
  canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', cinema.mouseOnSeat, false);
}

var Cinema = (function () {
  function Cinema(rows, seatsPerRow) {
    this.seats = [];
    this.rows = rows;
    this.seatsPerRow = seatsPerRow;

    var seatSize = 20;
    var seatSpacing = 3;
    var rowSpacing = 5;

    var i;
    var j;
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < seatsPerRow; j++) {
            this.seats[(i * seatsPerRow) + j] = new Seat(i, j, new Rect(j * (seatSize +   seatSpacing), i * (seatSize + rowSpacing), seatSize, seatSize));
        }
    }
  }

  Cinema.prototype.mouseOnSeat = function (event) {
    //somehow this is null
    if (this.seats == null) {
        alert("seats was null");
        return;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < this.seats.length; i++) {
        var s = this.seats[i];
        if (s.mouseOnSeat(event)) {
            alert("Mouse on a seat");
        }
    }
    alert("Mouse not on any seat");
  };

  Cinema.prototype.draw = function (canvasId) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById(canvasId);
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var i;
    //somehow this isn't
    for (i = 0; i < this.seats.length; i++) {
        var s = this.seats[i];
        context.beginPath();
        var rect = context.rect(s.rect.x, s.rect.y, s.rect.width, s.rect.height);
        context.fillStyle = 'green';
        context.fill();
    }
  };
  return Cinema;
})();
```

I tried a lot, like creating a self variable (`var self = this` ) and then calling from `self.mouseOnSeat`, it was suggested on another post, but I didn't figure it out.

Comment: What is line 29? Could you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: Are you sure that the two definitions of `Cinema` are not conflicting?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2eu7841h/, it is now in line 32

Comment: Creating the `self` variable only works if your function definition is inside the function that has the correct `this`. For example if you did not have a separate `mouseOnSeat` function but defined that function inline inside the `addEventListener` call, you could use that trick to replace `this` with `self` and there would be no problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you call `addEventListener`, the variable `this` does not carry along to the function call. This means that `this` is not your object.

You workaround is sound, you can use it. Or alteratively change your `addEventListener` call to:

```
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', cinema.mouseOnSeat.bind(this), false);
```

Do note that you *might* need to use a polyfill to get `Function.prototype.bind` for older browsers, although it is very well supported currently. See [caniuse](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#Function.prototype.bind).

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround :
`canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function (event) {
       cinema.mouseOnSeat(event);
    }, false);`

But I have no clue why